# BMI count doesn't work

Tags: swift

I want to calculate BMI value.
I have an add controller with two text fields for weight and height. Then I have a label for the result and a button to calculate the BMI value.

My code is:

```
@IBOutlet var fieldAltezza: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var fieldPeso: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var labelResult: UILabel!


@IBAction func calcBmi(sender: AnyObject) {

        var h = (fieldAltezza.text as NSString)
        var w = (fieldPeso.text as NSString)


        labelResult = w / (h*h)
        labelResult.text = NSString (format: "%2f m", h) as String
    }
```

but it doesn't work, I hope that someone will help me to find the error, kind regards.

Comment: Define _"it doesn't work"_.

Comment: I have the error Could not find an overload for '*' that accepts the supplied arguments in this line: 

labelResult = w / (h*h)

Comment: Well, you're trying to multiply String values (`h` and `w`)...

Comment: You have to convert it to string if you want to assign value to `labelResult`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dividing and multiplying `NSString` which is not possible here so convert your `h` and `W` to Float or whatever you want. After that you can assign label text this way:

```
labelResult.text = "\(w / (h * h))"
```

And your code will be :

```
@IBAction func calcBmi(sender: AnyObject) {

    var h = (fieldAltezza.text as NSString).floatValue
    var w = (fieldPeso.text as NSString).floatValue


    labelResult.text = "\(w / (h * h))"
    labelResult.text = String(format: "%.2f m", h)
}
```

Comment: Just want to let OP know there's no need to convert it to `NSString` first. `labelResult.text = String(format: "%.2f m", h)` should be enough :)

Comment: Hi Dharmesh Kheni,
thank you for your answer. I have modified my code:

<pre>
@IBAction func calcBmi(sender: AnyObject) {
        
        var h = (fieldAltezza.text as NSString).floatValue
        var w = (fieldPeso.text as NSString).floatValue
        fieldAltezza.text = NSString (format: "%.2f m", h) as String
        fieldPeso.text = NSString (format: "%.2f kg", w) as String
        
        
        labelResult.text = "\(w / (h * h))"
        labelResult.text = NSString (format: "Il tuo bmi è %.2f", labelResult) as String
    }
</pre>

but the result of the count is 0.00.

Comment: Thank you a lot :)
An information, how do you add code in comments? I have tried to add code with the grey background because it's more readable, but i don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe i have not explained well my doubt. The swift code works well. I asked you, how do you add code snippets in stackoverflow comments. I saw that the code in your comment is divided from the simple text because is  more readable. I have tried it in my comments but it doesn't work. I saw also this guide: 

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: add your code `` between this two.as mentioned into your link **inline``code in backticks``,**

Comment: Remove unwanted comment from here if you doesn't need it..:)